# My Header Menu Button 'Disappears' When The Header Becomes 'Sticky' Consultexo Theme Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-5

The menu icon located at the top right of my screen disappears when the page is scrolled & the header item becomes sticky. I have tried changing colours but the problem remains the same. I've tried altering the CSS manually & with different WordPress plugins. I've had no results.

**Notice the menu icon on the right.**
[image: menu before scrolling]

**This is what happens after scrolling.**
[image: menu icon after scrolling]

Comment: Please include the relevant code to the question (using the "edit" link), in your case the CSS applied to your element when sticky and not, and specify what you have tried when "altering the CSS manually"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the header has style position: relative;
And the menu button is absolute, so when you change header position to sticky, header is not relative for menu button already.

Try wrap menu button with div tag, and set position relative to it.

Comment: You should wait for the OP to add details before answering, or wait until you have enough reputation to comments. With CSS it can really be anything, dimensionning, floating issues etc that can make the button not to appear

Comment: The issue happens when position changes to sticky , it is logical that it is positioning issue.

Comment: It's probable I agree, but it can really be anything from another style added at the same moment to a syntax error, and depending on the OP's CSS, adding a div wrapper can break other things

Comment: I suggested one of the possible options that could be assumed with the available information, it is better to wait for the author's response, not yours